# Is there any way to remove a specific view path from a controller view paths at runtime?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, view, view-path

I'm working on a rails 3 application which has different sub domains for specific users or mobile devices.

This is how the view structure looks like:

app/

----views/

--------mobile/

--------admin/

It is possible to add a new view path to the pathset by simple calling

```
prepend_view_path(some_path)
```

or

```
append_view_path(some_path)
```

Now, I would like to remove them too.

Is there any way to remove any of the previously added paths from a controllers path_set?
I didn't find any useful methods in the API and when using the standard methods I'd use on an array (like `delete_at` for instance) I get following RuntimeError:

```
can't modify frozen array
```

I already use different mime types for request from mobile devices for instance. It is not too bad if I can't remove added paths. I'm just looking for a way to reset to the "default" view paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails provides other two getter and setter methods - [view_paths()](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/view_paths/class) and [view_paths=](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/view_paths=/class) methods respectively. I believe using 'view_paths=' method, you can remove the dynamically appended view path.

Comment: Thank you. Apparently, there is really no other way to delete entries from the view paths.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to prohibit ordinary users from using admin functionality. The better way is to use an 'authorization' plugin like ['cancan'](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan).